# Have any herbal/natural supplements been proven to have benefits to cognitive functioning?

Tags: supplement, cognitive-science, memory

There are no shortage of online sources that tout the benefits of ginkgo, fish oil, ginseng, Piracetam, choline, etc etc. But when I check out their WIkipedia pages, it looks as if there is no real evidence for improved cognitive functioning. I guess this is because, for one thing, cognitive functioning is not something that is easily measured for any number of reasons.

Nonetheless, I wonder if any nutritionists or experts in supplements here know of any preliminary evidence on the validity of a supplement or herb to improve, for example, memory, alertness, concentration, etc.

Obviously, there's exercise, meditation and caffeine... But are any of these other supplements worth considering?

Comment: "Cognitive function", is very jaded and a great example of overly broad terminology. Contrary to the rest, I can assure you that 'Choline' does support cognitive function or more formally, neural function, being that Choline is a precursor to the Neurotransmitter, Acetylcholine. Shown here: http://nba.uth.tmc.edu/neuroscience/m/s1/chapter11.html